# NGINX Redirect without rewriting the url excluding IP and directory

Tags: configuration, url-rewriting, nginx

We've got a page that we put up on our website when we take it down for maintenance or updates. The basic pseudocode logic looks something like this:

```
if IP != 72.56.43.212 and location !~ /down then
   display down/
```

It's important that the url remain intact. For example,

```
Address Bar: http://www.example.com/abcd.html
Page Shown:  http://www.example.com/down
```

I'm still pretty new to NGINX configuration. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: So just wondering, why do you check the location != down? why not just use the IP ?

Comment: I need to exclude down so it doesn't go into a redirect loop, rewriting the url it's being rewritten to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
location /down {
   #empty block
}
location / {
    if ($remote_addr != 72.56.43.212) {
       rewrite ^ /down/index.php last;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($remote_addr != "1.1.1.1") {
  rewrite . /down last;
}
```

Comment: This solves one of the issues. There are 3 that need solved concurrently. With this solution, I would get: 

http://www.example.com/abcd.html ...redirected to...
http://www.example.com/down ...redirected to...
http://www.example.com/down ...redirected to...
http://www.example.com/down ...redirected to...
http://www.example.com/down ...and so on...

Comment: This is internal redirect, so you will get content of /down. And the address line will no changed from /abcd.html.

Answer (score 0):

Never really tried this my self before, but you can use the nginx access rules to do this

```
error_page  403  http://example.com/down.html;
location / {
    allow 72.56.43.212;
    deny all;
}
```